# Вопрос по включению ЧПУ в opencart 2.1.0.2 и поисковикам

Tags: url, seo, redirect, opencart, чпу

Ситуация такова:
Есть [магазин](http://dalcompass.ru), который около полугода назад был переведен на opencart, а про включение ЧПУ владельцы, видимо, запамятовали. Сейчас есть задача это самое ЧПУ включить, но у меня, человека неопытного в SEO, встает вопрос: а не стоит ли удалить из кэша поисковиков старые "урлы"?

С одной стороны, опытным путем обнаружено, что с "не-ЧПУ" ссылок зайти на нужную страницу можно, и в строке пути браузера отображается новый, кошерный ЧПУ.  И терять, пусть и не первые, позиции в выдаче совсе-е-ем неохота.

С другой: а не воспримут ли поисковики по простоте душевной появление нового пути как дублирование контента?

Да, и вообще буду благодарен за любые советы по сайту.

Answer (score 0):

Что бы, при включении в opencart2 чпу, дублирования контента не происходило, необходимо в robots.txt закрыть все роуты, к которым применены чпу. Не уверен, что это единственное правильное решение, но на наших opencart проектах такое работает.

```
Disallow: /*?*
Disallow: /*?
Disallow: /*&
Disallow: /*&*
```

И, если мы коснулись сео, рекомендую пересадить сайт на ssl.

Answer (score 0):

нет не стоит, делаете со всех станиц без цпу 301 редирект на чпу, вес страницы полностью передается на чпу